# Exponential integral made arbitrarily small?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What can we say about the following integral, for $\alpha > 0$?

$$\int_{0}^{\epsilon} \exp{\left({-1} \over {(1-r^2)^{\alpha}}\right)} r \, dr$$

In particular, can it be made as small as we like as $\epsilon \to 0$? What "nice" function does it behave like in terms of epsilon?

EDIT: Can we also see that

$$1- \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \exp{\left({-1} \over {(1-r^2)^{\alpha}}\right)} r \, dr?$$ goes to $0$ with $\epsilon$? If not, is there a way to make this go arbitrarily close to $0$ by choose $\epsilon$ appropriately between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: In regards to your edit, if $f(\epsilon) \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ then $1-f(\epsilon) \to 1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. Further, if $0 < \epsilon < 1$ then Jason showed that your integral is less than $\epsilon^2/2$, so $$1- \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \exp{\left({-1} \over {(1-r^2)^{\alpha}}\right)} r \, dr \geq 1 - \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} \geq 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2},$$ so there is no way to choose $\epsilon$ in the interval $(0,1)$ to make this close to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $0<\exp\left(-\frac{1}{(1-r^2)^\alpha}\right)\le1$ if $0\le r\le\epsilon<1$, so
$$0<\int_0^\epsilon\exp\left(-\frac{1}{(1-r^2)^\alpha}\right)r\,\mathrm dr\le\int_0^\epsilon r\,\mathrm dr=\frac{\epsilon^2}2\to0.$$
In particular the integral is $O(\epsilon^2)$ as $\epsilon\to0$. Sharper bounds may be possible.

EDIT: You can also find a lower bound, but it's not as nice. Simply note that $\exp(-(1-r^2)^{-\alpha})\ge\exp(-(1-\epsilon^2)^{-\alpha})$ if $0\le r\le\epsilon$, so the same calculation as above gives you a lower bound of $\exp(-(1-\epsilon^2)^{-\alpha})\frac{\epsilon^2}2$.

Comment: How does $\int_0^\epsilon \epsilon dr=\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$?  I believe you meant $\int_0^\epsilon r dr=\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$

Comment: Oops, well spotted. I should have coffee before I do math in the morning -_-

Comment: Now that was funny!  ;-))

Comment: ... +1 ... You could go further and expand the exponential in a series and integrate term by term to generate a series solution.

Comment: I'll give you the checkmark for sure, but I may have some future questions about this within the week! Thanks Jason/commenters! Rather easy estimate...I completely neglected the negative sign, as I was working on this before my coffee, too! One thing also comes to mind which may be even more pressing: Can we bound that integral below by something positive which also goes to 0 with epsilon?

Comment: Essentially I am also interested in 1 minus this integral also going to 0 with epsilon if possible..

Comment: What you're asking for is different so simply saying 1 minus the integral goes to zero; as Antonio Vargas points out, this latter claim is impossible. I will edit in a lower bound, however.

Comment: But, what we do have is that the same integral with limits from $\epsilon$ to $1$ can be made arbitrarily small, yes?

Comment: Sure, as $\epsilon\to1$. As $r\to1$ the function goes to zero, so you can still bound the integrand by $1$ and get an upper bound of $1-\epsilon$.